# Reordering expressions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I have an expression such as `5x^2 / 3x * 6x / 2 *100 + 5`

Is there any way I can reorder the expression and keep its meaning

I know if it is just addition and subtraction only its cool.

I do understand using BIMDAS or what other name people give it when it comes to simplifying or evaluation but I want to know the rules about reordering if any?

Blair

Answer (score 2):

There are of course formal rules about the order of operation, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations for example.

These are not mathematical rules. They are conventions about how we interpret equations. They are a form of human communication; a notation. We could equally well have different rules.

In practice, an equation like your example seldom/never appears. Because to work it out, you need to think about the rules of precedence, so its not immediately clear what it means. It would normally be written with fractions having obvious numerators and denominators and brackets to make it clearer.